# Apache configure with mod_wsgi calling before_first_request on each call

Tags: python, apache, caching, flask, mod-wsgi

I want to load 6GB files into memory, so that if i receive the request i don't have to load it again. So i was able to achieve this on flask server by adding simple decorator @app.before_first_request but when i integrated apache with the same app it's calling this function before each request.

My code is following:

route.py

```
@app.before_first_request
def initialize():
    global SRC_PATH, MODEL
    path = SRC_PATH
    print("Loading Core files from {}".format(path))
    MODEL = Model.load(path+utils.MODEL_EXT)
    print("Loaded all files in memory")

@app.route("/test",methods=['POST'])
def search_index():
    # MyCode:
    return "some response"
```

My apache configurations are:

```
<VirtualHost *>
    WSGIDaemonProcess yourapplication user=ubuntu group=www-data
    WSGIScriptAlias / /xxx/app.wsgi
    <Directory /xxx/>
        WSGIProcessGroup yourapplication
        WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
<VirtualHost *>
```

and app.wsgi

```
import sys
import logging
logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stderr)
sys.path.insert(0, "/xxx/")
from route import app as application
```

Now in my apache logs on every request it's loading the core files:
apache.log

```
[Sun Oct 29 06:21:14.691075 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 22906:tid 140496053819136] Loading Core files from /xxx
[Sun Oct 29 06:21:20.919143 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 22906:tid 140496053819136] Loaded all files in memory
```

While i want this to be loaded on or even before the first request and keep it persistent to memory permanently ?

Comment: Just to make sure you haven't mucked up your Apache configuration and are somehow running the WSGI application in embedded mode, add ``WSGIRestrictEmbedded On`` outside of ``VirtualHost``.

Comment: You are also better off just loading the data at global scope in the WSGI script file, as that code only gets executed once. No need to muck with the decorator.

Comment: You are right i did the same on non flask version and it worked as expected. Now i have integrated Flask  and trying to run it. I have tried with WSGIRestrictEmbedded but nothing happens same effects also there is no app.run command in my whole file so how i am running wsgi embedded mode ?

Comment: If using ``WSGIRestrictEmbedded`` doesn't change anything, that is good and just eliminates the chance that mod_wsgi configuration was causing that, meaning that Apache could be spinning up new processes occassionally with your application, causing constant loading.

Comment: The next thing would be to have ``LogLevel`` in Apache set to ``info`` and what mod_wsgi log messages about when daemon processes are being stopped and started. Once started the process should stay running, but if processes were crashing at the end of requests for some reason, that would show up. You can also log process ID in your messages to see which process loading is occurring in.

Comment: One possibility is that ``before_for_request`` is actually per thread in a multi threaded process and not per process. Could log ``threading.current_thread().ident()`` to see if changes for same process each time it occurs.

Comment: Yes, that was the reason i figured it out earlier. Anyway, Post it as answer.

Comment: By the way before_for_request has the code inside which was using multiprocess so changing it to threads solve my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My issue was that inside the code I was using multiprocessing to load the files.

So instead of doing multiprocess i have changed it to multi threads.

So previously the code that was using multiprocess was as following:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
```

I have updated it to

```
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool
```

Where `multiprocessing.dummy` is threads based not process based.